# How to call functors stored in a map?

Tags: c++

I have a base class and a class, that are supposed to be functors, like this:

```
class BFunctor {};

class Add : public BFunctor {
public:
    int operator()(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
};
```

I intend to create several of these sub-classes and store pointers to them in a map called ops, like so:

```
map<string, BFunctor*> ops {};
Add add;
ops["sum"] = &add;
```

However, after doing that, why can't I use the function objects like so:

```
int x = ops["sum"](3, 5);
```

My linter says "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type"

And the compiler says "error: expression cannot be used as a function".

Comment: A `BFunctor` has no member functions, so there is nothing to call with a pointer to a `BFunctor`. Do you know if *every* `BFunctor` has a `int operator()(int x, int y)`?

Comment: `BFunctor` deos not define `operator()`. Also you need `virtual` to make it work properly.

Comment: Hi, @FrançoisAndrieux, thanks for the prompt answer. So my base class cannot be empty, right? How can I define it generically, so that the behavior of the functors can be set in the sub-classes?

Comment: @BernardoSOUSA add `virtual int operator()(int, int) = 0;` in `BFunctor`.

Comment: @BernardoSOUSA Seems you are looking for polymorphism. Luckily for you it's a feature c++ supports naively. You should read about the [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) keyword.

Comment: I just added the virtual function to BFunctor, but both the linter and the compiler keep saying the same thing.

Comment: Because that was only one of your problems. See the excellent answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to define members in `BFunctor` that you wish to use, in this case `operator()`

```
class BFunctor {
    virtual int operator()(int x, int y) = 0;
};

class Add : public BFunctor {
public:
    int operator()(int x, int y) override {
        return x + y;
    }
};
```

You also need to dereference the pointer stored in the map, as a pointer *also* doesn't have an `operator()`.

```
std::map<string, BFunctor*> ops {};
Add add;
ops["sum"] = &add;

int x = (*ops["sum"])(3, 5);
```

But you don't need to do this yourself. It [already exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) in the [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```
#include <functional>
using BFunctor = std::function<int(int, int)>;
using Add = std::plus<int>;

int main() {
    std::map<string, BFunctor> ops {};
    Add add;
    ops["sum"] = add;

    int x = ops["sum"](3, 5);
}
```

Comment: Suppose I did need to implement it myself. Suppose the behavior was slightly different then the one provided by std::sum. How could it be done so that the functor could be called through the map the same way std::sum is called (without de-referencing)? I need to store all sorts of functors on that map, and they all need to be called the same way: ops["operation_name"](arg1, arg2); In fact, I can't change the caller.

Comment: @BernardoSOUSA a `std::function<int(int, int)>` can hold any type with an `operator()` which can take two `int`s and return an `int`. Anything like your `Add` is perfectly fine. You don't have to inherit anything

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues.

As already mentioned in the comments, there's no `operator()` in the base class, so if you want to call through the pointer to it, you'll have to provide one (possibly without implementation) and also make it `virtual`, so it can dispatch to the correct derived class.

Secondly, you have a pointer to a class, so you can't call through it like you would through pointer-to-a-function - you have to dereference it first:

```
(*ops["sum"])(3, 5);
```

or, if you want:

```
ops["sum"]->operator()(3,5);
```

Full example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18a7f2e05eb8de80).